# Oracle Driver vs JDBC vs. close implementation

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

We have an external server service running Oracle and we can not access his configuration. We have the code for the application and we are interested in the current implementation of connection.close().

So the question is, running a Oracle 12c database, is it possible to connect to the database using older database driver version such as Oracle 11g? We want to exclude a simple configuration problem by drivers not matching the database product version.

Is there any document (other than JavaDoc) that specificates the implementation behaviour of Connection.close() since the Java spec says its implementation depending and there is no general rule.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02

Comment: The solution was that oracle always commits on close. Something that I tend to forget since I work mostly with serious Driver implementations (it is beyond me why a connection should be commited on close? Rollback seams to be more logical). But it is what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Metalink access, you can check [MOS note 207303.1 on Client-server interoperability](https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=207303.1).

In summary, Clients 11.2.0 and above are fully supported; 11.1.0 is supported, but bugfixes are possible only for customers with Extended support.